# Backpropagation in Pooling Layer (Subsamplig layer) in CNN

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, convolution, conv-neural-network, backpropagation

My doubt is how do I backpropagate error in the Pooling layer, because when I calculate the derivative, there is only 1 element of 4 (for example, when using a 2x2 pooling kernel) that affects the result of the feedforward.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because http://datascience.stackexchange.com

Comment: How can i move this post to http://datascience.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: Don't worry - the community will decide if this should be done. If 5 people (and a moderator?) think so, then it will be moved automatically and you will get a notice.

Comment: @Martin Thomas: Not sure this is off-topic, after all there is a backpropagation tag on SO, and the question concerns its implementation. Anyhow I don't have enough reputation to have a says in this :)

Answer (score 14):

Suppose you have a matrix **M** of four elements

```
a  b
c  d
```

and **maxpool(M)** returns **d**. Then, the maxpool function really only depends on **d**. So, the derivative of maxpool relative to **d** is 1, and its derivative relative to **a,b,c** is zero. So you backpropagate **1** to the unit corresponding to **d**, and you backpropagate zero for the other units.